# Need to Store Multiple users using checkboxes in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to store user details using checkboxes. For example, is there 2 or more users need to create new rows in the database and need to store it. Here is the controller function I wrote, which is not working. It stores only the last user details in the table, and pls note data checkbox data passes as an array.

```
public function enrolling(Request $request){
        // dd($request->checkboxes); THIS IS FOR CHECKING PURPOSR YOU CAN CHECK TEACHER AUTH WORKABILITY BY UNCOMMENTING THIS!
  
        $user_id=Auth::user()->teacher_id;

        $enroll=new Enroll();

        $size=$request->checkboxes;
        $sizelen=count($size);

        for($x=0; $x<=$sizelen;$x++){
            $enroll->techer_id=$user_id;
            $enroll->student_id=$request->checkboxes;
            foreach($request->checkboxes as $chkbox){
                $enroll->student_id=$chkbox; 
            }
            // $enroll->student_id=json_encode($request->checkboxes);
            $enroll->subject=$request->subject;
            $enroll->marks=random_int(0,100);

            $enroll->save();

        }

        return redirect('teacher/dashbord')->with('alert','Studetns Added Successfully');
    }
```

blade file that passe the data

```
<tbody>
   @if(isset($studentlist))
      @if(count($studentlist) >0)
       @foreach($studentlist as $student)
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="form-check">
               <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{$student->id}}" name="checkboxes[{{$student->id}}]">
            </div>                              
          </td>
          <td>{{$student->id}}</td>
          <td>{{$student->name}}</td>
          <td>{{$student->email}}</td>
         </tr>
       @endforeach
     @else
       <tr>
         <td colspan="4" class="text-center font-weight-bold text-danger mt-4">No Any Student Found!</td>
         </tr>
    @endif
  @endif
</tbody>
```

here's the pic of frontend view..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use insert method to insert multiple records into table

```
public function enrolling(Request $request){
    // dd($request->checkboxes); THIS IS FOR CHECKING PURPOSR YOU CAN CHECK TEACHER AUTH WORKABILITY BY UNCOMMENTING THIS!

    $user_id= Auth::user()->teacher_id;

    $insertedData = [];

    foreach($request->checkboxes as $studentId) {
        $insertedData[] = [
            'techer_id' => $user_id,
            'student_id' => $studentId,
            'subject' => $request->subject,
            'marks' => random_int(0,100)
        ];
    }

    Enroll::insert($insertedData); 

    return redirect('teacher/dashbord')->with('alert','Studetns Added Successfully');
}
```